# VASIMR technology for a manned trip to Saturn

Tags: engines, saturn, magnetoplasmadynamic

I finished reading the novel "Saturn Run" by John Sandford and Ctein.  Putting aside storyline and content of the novel there was a very interesting [Author's note](http://epubbookonline.com/b/2317/john-sandford/saturn-run-2015-/71) that explains how the science portion was written and that it may be plausible.

Let me focus my question.  *Is it possible with our current VASIMR spaceship technology that a manned trip to Saturn and back to Earth is plausible?*

The book gives a 6 month timeline from launch to Saturn and about the same time frame to get back to Earth.    In order to avoid too much speculation I will stick with this time.

Please note any spoilers with the link I posted.

The United States ship is described below.

> The Americans need something better. Enter the VASIMR engines. VASIMR stands for “Variable Specific Impulse Magnetoplasma Rocket.” “Specific impulse” is how rocket scientists refer to exhaust velocity. We didn’t make the VASIMR up. They’re being tested on Earth, fairly small ones. Ours are a lot bigger, and a little better-performing, but it’s fifty years from now. For a trip time of four to five months, we were able to get the ship down to a mass ratio of 10 with an exhaust velocity that varied from 35 up to 300 km/s. That’s about half the mass ratio we could come up with for a fixed-specific-impulse ship of any remotely plausible design.
>
> Exhaust velocity is the magic number. As long as the total delta-vee you want is less than your exhaust velocity, the amount of reaction mass you need isn’t too bad.

Comment: I can understand why you are interested, but this is too much to handle in one answer, and also it would be necessary to speculate a lot, which we try to keep to a minimum. If you are really interested in knowing about this, try breaking it up into several questions that can be answered in a page or so of text. Both kinds of engines do exist, they can be talked about if you want to ask about them. There are many unresolved health questions concerning deep space crewed spaceflight. That is best handled separately too.

Comment: @kimholder I will edit the question for brevity.

Comment: When we get people to Mars we'll have a better idea of when & how we'll be able to get people beyond Mars to places like Saturn

Comment: This is entirely possible *technically* and entirely impossible *politically*. Without another cold war + space race, the space program will never obtain necessary funding for the required research. But should some political miracle happen and both the funds would appear, at amounts similar to the Apollo program, and simultaneously some motivation to pick Saturn as the destination over many other, more attractive destinations, yes, we could do it in 50 years. But in the current political climate this is not going to happen.

Comment: There's little doubt Orion could do it with today's tech.  Thus it certainly is possible within 50 years.

Comment: You could choose to refocus the question or raise a new one to move the idea along. If you are specifically interested in the example you gave, VASIMR, then depending on the parameters of the mission you have in mind it might be easy to work out scale of the electrical power required. It could very easily be megawatts given the suggested figure of 300km/s

Comment: I will edit the question to focus more on the VASMIR.

Comment: In the interest of light entertainment I have done a quick sum based on 300km/s and ten tonnes dry mass - just a placeholder, I did say light entertainment. Anyway, Brachistochrone trajectory from here http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/appmissiontable.php, 5 months -> delta V = 1.4 million m/s (Remember https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V34jc8UGg9E) thus ~1000 tonnes propellant and power = 3.5MW. If the powers that be re-open the question I will set out the sums so people can correct my wild assumptions, or just have a chuckle.

Comment: oops, laugh a minute, I had a nagging feeling it was a bit low, checked and found I'd inadvertently missed a factor of 10^3, easily done. So, same starting numbers but power = 3.5 GW.

Comment: @Puffin: Seems like a job for a nuclear reactor... and if you pack one on board you might go with NTR instead, to simplify the matters. Nevertheless, 12 months roundtrip sounds is an awfully tight schedule requiring a very non-optimal transfer. 6.48 km/s at 9.2 years with a Jupiter flyby, 15.2 year at 6.89km/s for a [round-trip](http://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php?maxMag=25&chk_maxOCC=on&maxOCC=4&chk_target_list=on&target_list=Saturn&mission_class=roundtrip&mission_type=rendezvous&LD1=2014&LD2=2016&maxDT=21.0&DTunit=yrs&maxDV=20.0&min=DV&wdw_width=0&submit=Search#a_load_results).

Comment: Yes, horrendous, or just plain comic depending on one's perspective. "Optimum" has to be redfined here to mean "for the context of 6 months each way" and even then may reference concepts such as "mass optimum for that max journey time, with sheilding and crew consummables".

Comment: @SF I just read this question http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14542/could-a-spacecraft-take-off-from-earth-using-nuclear-thermal-rockets and it reminded me of the Saturn round trip. One response mentions NERVA which I looked up on Wiki - 300kN and 850s Isp.  (i.e. 8km/s and 1.2GW beam power) so more than enough thrust but way too little exhaust velocity for the delta-V I posted. As an aside I think that delta-V could be rather pessimistic as I had just taken the 5 month round trip figure as the nearest to hand.

Comment: How many more "Reopen" votes do we need?

Comment: @Puffin: 5. And while I agree with 300km/s the only way to go is ion engines, 300km/s is a truly staggering value, that's over 0.1%c ! Something of order of 8km/s from LEO for a spaceship with 15 years worth of supplies, simulated gravity, a nuclear reactor, radiation shielding, and all the goodies needed for such a trip is something much more realistic. (the step up in carried mass from a yearly mission to a 15-years mission is nowhere as big as from 8km/s to 300km/s delta-V, regardless of engines used.)

Comment: I agree, I wasn't vouching for a practical solution, just following the consequences of the starting assumptions, which included the Ve = 300km/s. Your last sentence cross-wired Ve with delta V, though your conclusion is still fine as my delta V estimate was absurdly high too. I see this as a stepping off point to scope the range of solutions as one tries to obtain shorter round trips, e.g. the "what is possible but not necessarily to be seen in our lifetime".

Comment: Recently, I studied similar problem a lot. They key is specific mass of the reactor. The most optimistic future power sources are estimated to 1 kg/kW mark. Then if we consider 100 ton ship with 50 tons 50 MW power system and VASIMR engines, we arrive at graph like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5w83jo4b9b39bn/ISP_V0_100AU_50MW.png?dl=0). The values are in days - the optimum being slightly under 450 days. The Saturn Run is way too optimistic in the reactor specific mass.